# Unity.Mvc3 Resolve type of Interface<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm using Unity.Mvc3 in my project and it has embedded **UnityDependencyResolver**.

```
var container = BuildUnityContainer();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

and the BuildUnityContainer method looks like:

```
private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer()
        .RegisterType<IControllerActivator, HControllerActivator>()
        .RegisterType<IDatabaseFactory, DatabaseFactory>(
            new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IRepository<Article>, HRepository<Article>>()
        .RegisterType<IRepository<ContentBase>, HRepository<ContentBase>>()
        .RegisterType<IRepository<User>, HRepository<User>>()
        .RegisterType<IRepository<Profile>, HRepository<Profile>>();

    container.RegisterControllers();

    return container;
}
```

but when I try to resolve my type like this:

```
var users = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRepository<User>>();
```

I get the following exception:

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "Data.IRepository`1[Data.Models.User]", name = "(none)". Exception
>   occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The type HRepository`1 cannot be
>   constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.

What am I doing wrong? And is it actually possible to use `.RegisterType<IFoo<T>, Foo<T>>()`?
Maybe I need some kind of custom DependencyResolver?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do do should be possible.  Unity may not know how to build `HRepository<T>`.

What does the `HRepository<T>` class look like?  Specifically, what are the constructor parameters and do any of their types need to be registered with Unity?

Unity will not be able to resolve `HRepository<T>` if it does not know how to construct its parameters.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction! the problem was indeed the class itself. I used it as an abstract one previously and forgot to change that.. too bad there were no indication of that. cost me a lot of time :)

Comment: @OopsImAlive It did tell you that... "The type HRepository1 cannot be constructed"